# Close the gap between divs in a grid layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, css-grid

Can I show div-3 below div-1 ?

```
.div-1{ float:left; width:50%; background:red; height:100px;}
.div-2{ float:left; width:50%; background:green; height:300px;}
.div-3{ float:left; width:50%; background:blue; height:200px;}
```

Screenshot of design:

[image: Screenshot of design]

Comment: Post the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 2):

You can.

```
.div-1{ float:left; width:50%; background:red; height:100px;}
.div-2{ float:right; width:50%; background:green; height:300px;}
.div-3{ float:left; width:50%; background:blue; height:200px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

### CSS Flexbox

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 300px; /* necessary to force a wrap (value based on height of items) */
}

.div-1 {
  order: 1;
  height: 100px;
  width: 50%;
  background: red;
}

.div-2 {
  order: 3;
  height: 300px;
  width: 50%;
  background: green;
}

.div-3 {
  order: 2; /* remove from source order and display second */
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="div-1"></div>
  <div class="div-2"></div>
  <div class="div-3"></div>
</section>
```

**Browser Support**

Flexbox is supported by all major browsers, [except IE < 10](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

Some recent browser versions, such as Safari 8 and IE10, require [vendor prefixes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

For a quick way to add prefixes use [Autoprefixer](https://autoprefixer.github.io/).

More details in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276).

---

### CSS Grid

```css
section {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr; /* distribute container space evenly between
                                     two columns */
 }

.div-1 {
  grid-area: 1 / 1 / 2 / 2;       /* see note below */
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.div-2 {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / 3 / 3;
  height: 300px;
  background: green;
}

.div-3 {
  grid-area: 2 / 1 / 3 / 2;
  height: 200px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="div-1"></div>
  <div class="div-2"></div>
  <div class="div-3"></div>
</section>
```

The [**`grid-area`**](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#placement-shorthands) shorthand property parses values in this order:

- `grid-row-start`
- `grid-column-start`
- `grid-row-end`
- `grid-column-end`

Note the counter-clockwise direction, which is the opposite of `margin` and `padding`.

**Browser Support for CSS Grid**

- Chrome - full support as of March 8, 2017 (version 57)
- Firefox - full support as of March 6, 2017 (version 52)
- Safari - full support as of March 26, 2017 (version 10.1)
- Edge - full support as of October 16, 2017 (version 16)
- IE11 - no support for current spec; supports obsolete version

Here's the complete picture: http://caniuse.com/#search=grid

Comment: Can it be possible to remove section height? Can't fixed height on my website.

Comment: In flexbox, the container needs to have a height. Otherwise, the column of items has no reason to wrap. That's why I also posted a grid solution, which doesn't require a fixed height on the container.

Comment: Not working for my website: https://www.artguide.pro/paris-guide/    Screen 992px to 1199px right side.

Comment: You didn't mention you were using Bootstrap. That adds a layer of complexity. I edited the tags in your question. Maybe a Bootstrap expert will respond.

Answer (score 1):

The Bootstrap way is to simply use `pull-right` on the 2nd DIV...

```
<section>
  <div class="div-1"></div>
  <div class="div-2 pull-right"></div>
  <div class="div-3"></div>
</section>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/Cj0pAGoSxG